# Крестики-нолики через ооп №2

Tags: java, ооп, arraylist

В общем - пытаюсь создать немного более сложные ХО в ооп.
Есть классы игрока, счетчика игрока, менеджер игроков, игрового поля, основной рабочий класс.
Архитектура - в Main инициализируются начальные переменные. Там же происходит ввод игроков.
Далее предполагается вызов основного рабочего метода, с переменным включением игроков, манипулирую менеджером, простановка МЕТОК игроков, и проверка победителя/заполнения поля.

```
/**
 * Класс уникального номера игрока
 */
public class Count {
    int count;

    Count(int zero) {
        count=zero;
    }

    int getNextCount(Count count) {
        this.count++;
        return this.count;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Count{" +
                "count=" + count +
                '}';
    }
}

    
   
/**
 * класс игрока
 */
public class Player {
    Count count ;
    String name;
    int id;
    Scanner scanner;
    int[] coords;

    /**
     * Имя, номер пользователя
     */

    Player(String name, Count count) {
        this.name = name;
        id = count.getNextCount(count);
    }


    /**
     * рисование метки от пользователя
     */
    void madeTheMark(Player player, Field field, int[] coords) {
        if (player.id == 1) {
            field.markX(coords[0], coords[1]);
        } else {
            field.markO(coords[0], coords[1]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * метод создания пары координат от пользователя
     */

    int[] getCellCoords() {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите позицию по горизонтали(от 0 до 2):");
        int i = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Введите позицию по вертикали(от 0 до 2):");
        int j = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        int[] coords = new int[2];
        coords[0] = i;
        coords[1] = j;
        this.coords = coords;
        return this.coords;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player{" +
                "count=" + count +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

/**
 * класс манипулятор игроков
 */
public class PlayerManager {
    Count count;
    ArrayList<Player> players;
    Player player;

    PlayerManager() {
        players = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    void addPlayer(String name, Count count) {
        Player player = new Player(name, count);
        players.add(player);
    }

    Player getFirstPlayer() {
        return players.get(0);
    }

    Player getSecondPlayer() {
        return players.get(1);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PlayerManager{" +
                "count=" + count +
                ", players=" + players +
                '}';
    }

}

    
/**
 * игровой стартер и основной цикл
 */
public class Main {
    Scanner scanner;
    PlayerManager playerManager;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main start = new Main();
        PlayerManager manager = new PlayerManager();
        Count count = new Count(0);
        manager.addPlayer(start.playerInvitation(), count);
        manager.addPlayer(start.playerInvitation(), count);
        System.out.println(count);
        System.out.println(manager.players);

    }

    void runGame() {
        Field plate = new Field();

        plate.fillTheField();               //инициализация поля отображаемого для игроков
        plate.fillTheSpace();               //поле для вычислений
        plate.printFields();


//        mainCycle(plate);
    }

    /**
     * Основной цикл игры между 2 пользователями
     */

//
//    void mainCycle(Field plate) {
//        do {
////
//
//        } while (field.space.size() != 0);
//    }

    /**
     * приглашения пользователя
     */


    String playerInvitation() {
        System.out.println("Введите имя игрока: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = scanner.nextLine();

        return name;
    }


}
```

ВОПРОС :
1)
Вроде проинициализировал в Main Count.
Вроде Count считается. Но, не передается в конструктор Player.

```
Count{count=2}
[Player{count=null, name='654'}, Player{count=null, name='31'}]
```

Что, вот ТУТ, не так? :

```
  Player(String name, Count count) {
        this.name = name;
        id = count.getNextCount(count);
    }

 void addPlayer(String name, Count count) {
        Player player = new Player(name, count);
        players.add(player);
    }
```

P.S. нашел очепятку. исправил. вопрос пока закрыт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу 1 вопроса:

```
public class Player {
    Count count ;
    Field field;
    String name;
    static int id=0;
    Scanner scanner;
    int[] coords;

    /**
     * Имя, номер пользователя
     */

    Player() {
        id = count.getNextCount(count);
    }
```

В классе Player в конструкторе Player(), вы вызываете у объекта count метод getNextCount(count), но при этом сам то объект нигде не проинициализирован, поэтому он null, и получается это выглядит null.getNextCount(count) и вылетает NPE.

```
Player() {
    count = new Count(здесь надо вести число, так как ваш требует int (int zero));
    id = count.getNextCount(count);
}
```